# php wont let me echo JSON string

Tags: php

Throught an AJAX call I want to pick some data from DB and send back to client.
`$result` is return value of `SELECT QUERY`

**Case1:This works fine**

```
$str = "[";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $str = $str ."{". 

                            '"Name":'. '"'. $row["Name"] . '"'  

                       . "},";
    }
}
$str = $str . "]";
echo str;
```

**CASE2:This works fine too:**

```
$str = "[";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $str = $str ."{". 

                            '"ID":'. '"'. $row["ID"] //SEE HERE

                       . "},";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$str = $str . "]";

echo $str;
```

**CASE3: BUT FOLLOWING GIVES error with `500()`**

```
$str = "[";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $str = $str ."{". 

                            '"ID":'. '"'. $row["ID"] . '",'   //SEE HERE
                            '"Name":'. '"'. $row["Name"] . '"'


                       . "},";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$str = $str . "]";

echo $str;
```

I want to send echo str after making it in JSON format and parse it at client side using `JSON.parse(). Case1 and 2 work fine when I have only one key-value pair. But as soon as I put 2 key-value pairs I get error:

```
POST https://******************.php 500 ()
```

Comment: this isnt the best way my friend

Comment: @HBensiali I know. Can you tell me other way so that I can receive array of JS object on client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to use the appropriate functions.

Get into good programming habits.

```
$rtn = []; //create array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //push result into array
    $rtn[] = ['ID'=> $row["ID"], 'Name'=> $row['Name']]; 
}

if($rtn)//if array has entries
    echo json_encode($rtn);//encodes result to json
else
    echo "0 results";
```

Answer (score 1):

It return 500, because you have error in your script. You can add below code and check where is the mistake.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Probably in your code is missing dot. Check this:

```
$str = $str . "{" .

    '"ID":' . '"' . $row["ID"] . '",' .  
    '"Name":' . '"' . $row["Name"] . '"'

. "},";
```